# Get a full path of a file that has just been opened (window form application)

Tags: c++

So, I created a program with visual studio (Window form application with C++) to manipulate a certain type of file. After that, I set this program as default to open that type of file.
So of course, whenever I open a file of that type, the program runs. I just want to get the path of the file I have just opened , and write that path into a textBox for example. How do I do that?

Comment: Haven't worked much with Windows GUI applications, but I guess that the path is being transmitted in one of the main() function arguments. But I can't understand: if your application already opens the file, this means, that you are work with the path, so you can't dunno where it is. So what's the problem: is a path relative? Or what?

Comment: It is passed to you as a command line argument.  Pass the Main() method's *args* to your form constructor or use Environment::GetCommandLineArgs()

Comment: thanks, the Environment::GetCommandLineArgs() did work :)